# Непонятный отступ на мобильных устройствах

Tags: html, css

сайт http://gipstore.ru/
На мобильных устройства справа появляется белая полоса и соответственно полоса прокрутки. В чем проблема? Как от нее избавиться?

Скриншот http://prnt.sc/f1dzy1

Проблема присутствует в хроме через инструмент-разработчика. И на нескольких смартфонах

Comment: Желательно приложить к вопросу скриншот и код по возможности. У меня все работает нормально на вашем сайте, не вижу проблемы.

Comment: Тоже проблемы не вижу, опишите полностью ситуацию - какое разрешение, какое устройство, какой браузер, какой эмулятор, при каких действиях происходит то чего не должно быть, что конкретно нужно чтобы было?

Comment: Попробуйте добавить эти стили - html, body {
  overflow-x:hidden 
}

Answer (score 1):

Ответ из комментария soledar10, чтобы прописать в CSS вот это свойство

```
html, body { overflow-x:hidden; }
```

очень помог!

Answer (score 0):

Вот этот стиль должен помочь:

```
.py-3 {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо с `overflow-x: hidden;`, на всякий случай, важно заметить, что данный баг - баг хрома. Для того, чтобы в этом убедится, проследуйте на https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/ и прогоните свой сайт. Если он не ругнется, что у вас есть эти поля, значит, это именно с этой оперой вопрос.